# Fragments keep going back to the default position when MapView is Zoomed In/Out

Tags: android

I have an activity with 3 fragments displayed, a `MapActivity`, a `ListActivity`, and a (normal) `DetailsActivity`. The `ListActivity` and `DetailsActivity` is placed over the MapActivity.

There's a function to hide both ListActivity and DetailsActivity with an Animation, and `onAnimationEnd()` I set a new layout for the hidden Activity.

The problem I'm facing is, everytime one of the ListActivity or DetailsActivity hidden **(picture State 2)**, and then I pinch the screen on the MapActivity to zoom the map, it always goes back to the default view **(picture State 1)**. The closed Activities are automatically opened again.

Does anybody know how to prevent the hidden fragments from going to the first state again when I pinch the MapActivity?

this is an example of the function how I hide the DetailsActivity():

```
public void hideDetailview() {
        final Animation close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.close);
        close.setFillEnabled(true);
        close.setAnimationListener(closeDetailAnimationListener);
        fragment_detail.startAnimation(close);

        Toast.makeText(MainFragmentActivity.this,WWHApplication.getDrawer(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private AnimationListener closeDetailAnimationListener = new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


            int newLeft = -330;
            fragment_detail.layout(newLeft, 
                    fragment_detail.getTop(), 
                                newLeft + fragment_detail.getMeasuredWidth(), 
                                fragment_detail.getTop() + fragment_detail.getMeasuredHeight());

        }
    };
```

Here's the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.wwh"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_map_fragment1"
        android:name="com.wwh.fragments.MyMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/my_map_fragment -->
    </fragment>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/my_detail_fragment"
                android:name="com.wwh.fragments.DetailFragment"
                android:layout_width="380dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/border_detail"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/detail_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/my_list_fragment"
                android:name="com.wwh.fragments.MyListFragment"
                android:layout_width="380dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:shadowColor="#000000"
                android:shadowDx="1.2"
                android:shadowDy="12"
                android:shadowRadius="12" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/border_list"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/shadow_vertical"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shadow_vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: The normal default state, all fragments are opened]

[image: Second state, fragments are closed]

Comment: Are you manually implementing the pinch event on the map or you are just using the maps integrated zoom in controls?

Comment: I'm using the maps integrated zoom in controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've forgot to update the layout of the other fragments , perhaps?or maybe , you've got the wrong calculation of the new layout ?

i say this since animations on old android versions are tricky since they don't really change the layout of the views . so maybe when animation ends , you actually touch on something that you don't think you're touching .

please provide more code . maybe it could help us understand why it occurs.

btw , please rename the fragments classes . they are not activities , so why have "activity" in their names?

Comment: What do you mean by updating the layout actually? I only update the layout of the fragments on by using the method I have on animation ends.

Yes each fragment contains an activity actually, so I just name it with activity on my pics above.

Comment: I've added my code for the layout, as for the MapActivity it's just a normal mapView with integrated zoom. Or maybe you can ask me which code you need me to provide specifically

Comment: fragments do not contain activities . activities contain fragments . anyway , about what i've written , after the animation is finished , you need to update the layoutParams of the views that were created by the fragments , but i'm not sure if you already do that , since you did call to "layout" . i would prefer to set the layoutParams for each of the views instead.